# angular set dirty form within directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have an angular driven form using $dirty to spot for changes to enable/disable submit button.

Part of the form uses a Directive for uploading a logo but the form is noticing this as a changed element so upon setting a logo that validates in size I need to manually trigger that the form has had a change so should be a case of formName.$setDirty(); however console is saying that $setDirty() is not defined and I think this is because I am within a directive.

Within my directives controller upon file selection I call the function below and it is here when the file is valid that I would want to call the setdirty method.

```
function isFileValid(file) {
        vm.fileValid = true;
        vm.errorMessage = "";

        if (file.size > 16777216) {
            vm.errorMessage = "The File is too big!";
            vm.fileValid = false;
        } else if (file.size == 0) {
            vm.errorMessage = "The File is empty!";
            vm.fileValid = false;
        }

        if (vm.fileValid) {
            // make form dirty
            $setDirty();
        }

        return vm.fileValid;
    }
```

Here is the directive JS

```
(function () {
'use strict';
    .module("tpBusinessProfile")
    .directive("tpLogoUploader", tpLogoUploader);

function tpLogoUploader() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "tpLogoUploader.directive.html",
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            changedMethod: "&"
},
        controller: "tpLogoUploaderCtrl",
        controllerAs: 'logoCtrl',
        restrict: "E"
    };
}

})();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use directive require option and require controller of form directive:

```
{
     require: '^form'
```

and then in link function bind method that you need to your scope (dirty solution):

```
  link(scope, elem, attrs, formController){
      scope.makeFormDirty = formController.$setDirty
  }
```

and now you can use it in your controller via `makeFormDirty`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I added require and link to my directive however the form submit button is always selectable as it seems to be setdirty as soon as the page loads. if I comment out scope.makeFormDirty = formController.$setDirty() then the submit button is still locked; I hadnt even called makeformDirty at this stage. Thanks

Comment: sorry, of course it should be `scope.makeFormDirty = formController.$setDirty` not `$setDirty()`

Comment: Hi that's great thanks the submit button is still locked now which is correct - however when calling makeFormDirty from my directive its not unlocking the submit button do I need to reference the form name similar to how the submit buttons click status is controlled by ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pristine"